# Apache virtual host assigned folders

Tags: apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

**$ httpd -S** gives only the names of hosts, and the DocumentRoot is not seen. How can I see the assigned folders also?

I need like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /xampp/htdocs/gift
   ServerName gift.loc  
</VirtualHost>
```

But get like this:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server noelforte.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with apachectl for example

`apachectl -t -D DUMP_RUN_CFG`

Is it showing the info you are looking for?

Comment: No. Just wrote 'Syntax OK'

Comment: ```Syntax OK``` is outputed when I type apachectl -t only.

Comment: I wrote as you showed above. 
I don't have root right, may it influence? I don't want to edit, only to see

Comment: I don't think it should matter, I tried with an unprivileged user and had the same result. Can you confirm the version of apache you are running?

Comment: Any other suggestions?